# ESTA approved for October holiday to Texas, now I'm visiting CT to work for 2 weeks in June

Tags: esta

Do I need to update my US address contact to the one in CT??

Comment: Could you give more details? What is our citizen and so on?

Comment: @MarcelP unusually,that is not necessary here. OP has an ESTA and we know that the address _can_ be updated the question is whether it's _required_.

Comment: If it's possible to update the address, why not just do it?  It won't hurt anything.

Comment: Note that you should not be visiting "to work." The Visa Waiver Program is not an employment visa. What you can do is visit [for business](https://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/BusinessVisa%20Purpose%20Listings%20March%202014%20flier.pdf). That link lists various types of business purposes that are permissible. If you show up at the border and say you're there to work without an appropriate work visa, you'll be in for some questions, and could be sent back if things go poorly. It's fine to come for business or to attend meetings and be paid by a foreign source, but not "to work."

Answer (score 2):

In all documentation I can find for example https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/WebHelp/ESTA_Screen-Level_Online_Help_1.htm#uta1 it says "you can still update any one of the following fields" but nowhere does it say you *required* to do so. So, no, you will be fine but if you want to be 100% do it, it's not a big deal.